# Algorithm of finding node and its parent in tree data

Tags: javascript, algorithm, treeview

Let's say I have Javascript object structured below :

```
   const data = [{
    id: 1,
    type: "ORGANIZATION",
    children: [
        {
            id: 11,
            type: 'ORGANIZATION',
            children: [
                {
                    id: 111,
                    type: 'DEPARTMENT',
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: 1111,
                            type: 'DEPARTMENT',
                            children: null // final child
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 112,
                    type: 'DEPARTMENT',
                    children: [
                        //more children
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 12,
            type: 'DEPARTMENT',
            children: [
                //more children
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

In above structure, an `ORGANIZATION` node can have a list of smaller `ORGANIZATION` node and `DEPARTMENT` node, while `DEPARTMENT` node can have a list of smaller `DEPARTMENT`.
I'm trying to write an algorithm to get the closet parent of any node and the information of itself in the tree, following these rules:

- Algorithm will return 2 object `orgInfo` and `deptInfo`.
- If the node is `ORGANIZATION` type, return `orgInfo` with information itself and return `deptInfo` null.
- If the node is `DEPARTMENT` type, return the closet `orgInfo` and return `deptInfo` with information itself.

For example if the algorithm search for `id:1111` node , it will return `deptInfo` which has id = 1111 and `orgInfo` which has id = 11 (closet parent)

I already have my algorithm in Javascript but when I try to put it in my React Native app it rendered slowly. Here my code:

```
const itemSelector = createSelector( // using selector for Redux 
    [
        state => state.LookUpReducer.selectedItem,
        state => state.globalReducer.department_tree,
        
    ],
    (item, tree) => {
        let nodePath = [];
        let orgId, deptId;
        searchTree(tree, item.id, (item) => nodePath = [...item]);
        console.log(nodePath);
        nodePath.reverse().some(item => {//reverse the path to find the closet parent
            if (item.type == 'ORGANIZATION') {
                orgId = item.id
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
        nodePath.some(item => {
            if (item.type == 'DEPARTMENT') {
                deptId = item.id
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
        console.log("OrgID: " + orgId + " DeptID:" + deptId);
        return {
          .....
         }
    }
)

const searchTree = (tree, nodeId, callback, path = []) => {
//nodeId : the node to be search
    tree.forEach(item => {
        path.push({
            id: item.id,
            type: item.type
        });
        if (item.id == nodeId) {
            callback(path); // node founded
        }
        else {
            if (item.children) searchTree(item.children, nodeId, callback, path)
        }
        path.pop();
    })
}
```

I know that my algorithm is running through all the node in tree and I still don't know how to stop it when it finds the node. Anyone can help me to find a better solution for my algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a depth-first search, and when the loop is returning from the inner cycles, if a department is found but not the organization you can just set the first organization it crosses as it already runs in reverse order.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    type: "ORGANIZATION",
    children: [
        {
            id: 11,
            type: 'ORGANIZATION',
            children: [
                {
                    id: 111,
                    type: 'DEPARTMENT',
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: 1111,
                            type: 'DEPARTMENT',
                            children: null // final child
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 112,
                    type: 'DEPARTMENT',
                    children: [
                        //more children
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 12,
            type: 'DEPARTMENT',
            children: [
                //more children
            ]
        }
    ]
}]


let org, dep;

let loop = (nodes, id) => {
    if (org) {
        return; // when you have already fond the org
    }
    
    if(!nodes){
        return; // incase the final child
    }

    nodes.forEach(node => {
        if (node.id === id) {
            node.type === 'ORGANIZATION' ? org = node : dep = node; // if you find the org or dep no need to loop children
        } else {
            loop(node.children, id); // if not found go one level deeper.

            if (!org && dep && node.type === 'ORGANIZATION') { // on returning from deeper level when you have found department but not an organization yet set it here
                 org = node; 
            }
        }
    });

}

loop(data, 111);

console.log('organization :',org);
console.log('department :', dep);
```